# Side-effect vs non-destructive in lisp

Tags: haskell, lisp

For example in `Mathematica` programs to generate a new list for every operation performed on list is dramatically faster than in place manipulations in list(say append, drop etc).

`Haskell` also gives a new list by default for every operation performed on list.

I read that `lisp` provides both facilities, creating new list every time or choosing to do in place manipulations in list.

But I am confused as it also states that in place helps in reusing same list again and hence reduces garbage. So, which way is the effective, because I am seeing two great languages that say something opposite.

Comment: Not all languages are created equally. Lists in lisp are linked-lists, while Mathematica and Haskell probably (?) use something closer to an array.

Comment: @MicroVirus: array give poor performance than linked lists.

Comment: Anyone who wants to close it, can suggest something as well regarding improving this question. I am quite open to suggestions.

Comment: @MicroVirus: Haskell lists are linked lists, mainly because that allows evaluating (possibly infinite!) lists lazily. But actually arrays give _much better performance_ than lists, because they are continuous in memory, which gives much better cache use. For this reason, any decent language, no matter how much it likes lists, will also give you tight array types.

Comment: Each data structure has its strengths and weaknesses. Linked lists are better at random inserts than arrays, but poor at random access.
I guess the most confusing point here is that the name used for the actual underlying data structure is not the same in each language.
@leftaroundabout: Thanks, I'm not familiar with Haskell myself.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: but in case of arrays it is highly possible that so much contiguous space might not be available, so I think no one will use arrays unless they chose some heuristics based on list size etc.

Comment: @Rorschach: on the heap, any modern OS gives you continuous arrays as long as you like (as long as it fits in total memory, of course).

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I was wondering that it should be JVM's or compiler's heap rather than OS. In java there is random allocation and I don't think right usage cannot be made if arrays are used always.

Comment: Haskell is lazy so nothing is actually calculated until it's needed. No need to be TCO for it to be effiecent. In addition I'd guess the compiler actually does reuse/mutate. @leftaroundabout In Lisp and Haskell you can make lists of anything. Adding elements to front and remove from front is cheap while adding to the end is expensive. That's because it's a linked list! The only array involved is the call stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Immutable data structures let the compiler [reason about them easier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_%28computer_science%29).
(Some zealots have even argued that mutable data structures are a crutch for poor compilers. :-)

Mutable structures (arrays, lists, hash tables - all of them are present in Lisp) let one do some things easier, and they sometimes let the programmer micro-optimize the code, which was not all that stupid when the "[sufficiently smart compiler](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SufficientlySmartCompiler)" was even more of a pipe dream than it is now.

PS. It is not quite fair to compare Haskell and Mathematica with Lisp as they belong to different generations. Lisp is the second oldest programming language still in use (after Fortran) while Haskell and Mathematica build on 30+ years of CS research.

Comment: I understand I shouldn't compare them but looks like not many have taken in account for how it actually affects performance in case of large lists.

Comment: Right! This is the SSC and programmer-optimization I talk about.

Answer (score 2):

> But I am confused as it also states that in place helps in reusing
>   same list again and hence reduces garbage. So, which way is the
>   effective, because I am seeing two great languages that say something
>   opposite.

One of the main design goals of Haskell is easy reasoning. When all of your data structure is immutable, you get referential transparency. This make your code easy to reason about. Other advantages of this being easy concurrency and parallelism.

In Mathematica, they seem to be recommending use of immutable datastrucutres but also provide mutable data structures through emulation. Although, I don't think this is a great design decision, this according to them offers flexibility.

In Haskell, Lists are not the start and the end of data structures. There are many more: Set, Vector, Map, Array etc. Each data structure has it's own characteristics. For getting a good performance, I would suggest you to know the pros and cons of each one and use the right data structures according to your requirement. For most simple requirement, the usage of List suffices.

And if for some reason, you really want mutable data objects in Haskell, you may want to check out the ST monad.

Comment: I agree that there are other data structures available but what I need to know is specific to list. I am already aware of the info you have shared here.

Comment: The design of the GHC runtime uses generational garbage collection: short-lived objects are very cheap.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, immutable data structures make code easy to reason about. That isn't just for the programmer: the compiler can also reason about the code more easily.

For instance think about the following identity:

```
map (f . g) xs = (map f . map g) xs
```

If you don't know Haskell, "map f xs" applies function f to each element of list Xs in turn, giving you a new list, and "." is an operator that composes two functions together; the definition is "(f . g) x = f (g x)".

The identity above isn't part of the definition of "map", but its something you can prove by taking the defintions of map and "." as axioms and doing some substitution. What it says is that you can replace "map f . map g" (that is, two iterations through the list) with "map (f . g)" (that is, a single iteration doing "g" and then "f" to each item in turn). But this only works if you assume that "f" and "g" have no side effects. If their order of execution matters then the identity no longer holds. So you can only do this optimisation in languages where all values are immutable.

GHC lets the programmer assert these identities using [rewrite rules](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.1/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html). The actual rule set in Data.List is more sophisticated and general, but the one above is a special case that follows from the rules it gives.

So in Haskell you can write a long chain of list operations like

```
foo = take 5 . sortBy cmp . map f . filter pred . concatMap g
```

and have it compiled down into the optimal code. A language where values are mutable would have to execute each of those steps on the entire list, store the result in memory, and then move on to the next step. For large lists that would be too slow and/or memory hungry, so the above expression would have to be rewritten manually instead of just letting the compiler do it for you.